# How to create new list of sublists from specific elements of another list of sublists

Tags: python, list, sublist

I have a list of sublists. Each sublist is a sentence with string. I want to remove the third element of each list to create a new list from each sublists.
My code is like this :

I changed my code (update version):

```
for list in list_Pos:
    liste_globale = []
    nouvelle_liste = [] 
    for elt in list:
    first, second, third = elt.split()
    #print(first)
    #print(second)
        #print(third)       
    nouvelle_liste.append(third)
        liste_globale.append(nouvelle_liste)

print(liste_globale)
```

Update :  My list of sublist is like this :

```
      [ ['Moi\tPRO:PER\tmoi', 'je\tPRO:PER\tje', 'ne\tADV\tne', 'trouve\tVER:pres\ttrouver', 'pas\tADV\tpas', 'très\tADV\ttrès', 'esthétique\tADJ\testhétique', '.\tSENT\t.'], ['L’esthétique\tADJ\tL’esthétique', 'pêche\tNOM\tpêche', 'un\tDET:ART\tun', 'peu\tADV\tpeu', '.\tSENT\t.'], ['Cette\tPRO:DEM\tce', 'grosse\tADJ\tgros', 'prise\tNOM\tprise', 'là\tADV\tlà', '...\tPUN\t...'], ['Cette\tPRO:DEM\tce', 'prise\tNOM\tprise', 'puis\tADV\tpuis', 'la\tDET:ART\tle', 'borne\tNOM\tborne', ',\tPUN\t,', 'ça\tPRO:DEM\tcela', 'se\tPRO:PER\tse', 'voit\tVER:pres\tvoir', '.\tSENT\t.'], ['Derrière\tPRP\tderrière', 'la\tDET:ART\tle', 'télé\tNOM\ttélé', 'ça\tPRO:DEM\tcela', 'va\tVER:pres\taller', 'mais\tKON\tmais', '...\tPUN\t...'], ['Mais\tKON\tmais', 'vu\tVER:pper\tvoir', 'le\tDET:ART\tle', 'système\tNOM\tsystème', 'ça\tPRO:DEM\tcela', 'va\tVER:pres\taller', 'être\tVER:infi\têtre', 'difficile\tADJ\tdifficile', 'de\tPRP\tde', 'faire\tVER:infi\tfaire', 'plus\tADV\tplus', 'sobre\tADJ\tsobre', '!\tSENT\t!'], ['M\tNOM\tM', '.\tSENT\t.', 'Laudrel\tNAM\tLaudrel', 'est\tVER:pres\têtre', 'mort\tVER:pper\tmourir', 'hier\tADV\thier', 'soir\tNOM\tsoir', '.\tSENT\t.'], ['je\tPRO:PER\tje', 'viens\tVER:pres\tvenir', '2.2\tNUM\t@card@', ',\tPUN\t,', 'lo\tVER:pper\tlo', '.\tSENT\t.']]
```

My output is like this :

```
[['je', 'venir', '@card@', ',', 'lo', '.'], ['je', 'venir', '@card@', ',', 'lo', '.'], ['je', 'venir', '@card@', ',', 'lo', '.'], ['je', 'venir', '@card@', ',', 'lo', '.'], ['je', 'venir', '@card@', ',', 'lo', '.'], ['je', 'venir', '@card@', ',', 'lo', '.']]
```

Comment: Is each sublist meant to be split by `\t`?

Comment: I don't understand your expected output. Could you add more explanation to it?

Comment: @yatu  I want to split only the string containing  ''M\tNOM\tM' by the tabulation , that's why i am creating three variable : first, second, third and then i wish to retrieve in a sublist  the third index of each string in my list. Is is more comprehensible ?

Comment: Does my answer do what you want?

Comment: @Austin  , I have a list of sublists containg each list a list of string like this : ''M\tNOM\tM' , if i print the  element in a sublist, I have this configuration:   M NOM M  like column. and I want to retrieve the third element of each column.

Comment: @kely789456123, please update your output to match with your explanation, especially last element of second sublist.

Comment: @yatu which answer? using the tab to split?

Comment: My answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54443111/9698684

Comment: @Austin, ok   I am posting the whole answer.

Comment: @yatu , your solution is working, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Third element for each sub-list split along the tab character('\t').

The following solution matches your output sample:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

list_Pos = [
    ['M\tNOM\tM', '.\tSENT\t.', 'Laudrel\tNAM\tLaudrel'],
    ['Derrière\tPRP\tderrière','la\tDET:ART\tle',  'télé\tNOM\tt']
]


final_result = []

for sub_list in list_Pos:
    final_result.append([r.split("\t")[2] for r in sub_list])

print(final_result)
```

Output:

[['M', '.', 'Laudrel'], ['derrière', 'le', 't']]

Comment: You have changed the input `'Derriere != 'Derrière`

Comment: thank you very much, but it is the third element i want to retrieve because it is the lemma of the word iin the first place. I think changing the index to 2  will rget me the right word. Thank you very much.

Comment: @mad_ - I did that to not worry about non-latin1 chars so I could test quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Based on original edit output, you could use list comprehension for each element of each sublist in the range of length of sublist 1 (assuming all sublists are of same length)

```
lst = [['M\tNOM\tM', '.\tSENT\t.', 'Laudrel\tNAM\tLaudrel',],['Derrière\tPRP\tderrière','la\tDET:ART\tle',  'télé\tNOM\tt',]]
final_result = []
for x in range(len(lst[1])):
    lst1 = [[item.split('\t')[x] for item in sblst] for sblst in lst]
    final_result.append(lst1)
print(final_result)
```

To get only third element, remove for loop and run 
    `lst1 = [[item.split('\t')[2] for item in sblst] for sblst in lst]`
, where x is just set to 2.

Comment: Thank you, please don't forget to upvote/accept/share/like/high five.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `list comprehension` and [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) each string on `\t` and select the third elements. Using the first examples from your list:

```
l=[['M\tNOM\tM', '.\tSENT\t.', 'Laudrel\tNAM\tLaudrel'],['Derrière\tPRP\tderrière','la\tDET:ART\tle',  'télé\tNOM\tt']]
```

You could do:

```
[[i.split('\t')[2] for i in subl] for subl in l]
[['M', '.', 'Laudrel'], ['Derrière', 'la', 'télé']]
```

Comment: thank you Indeed your proposed code is working. thank you.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension `split()` and then fetch `[2]` element(third element)

```
test_list=[['M\tNOM\tM', '.\tSENT\t.', 'Laudrel\tNAM\tLaudrel'],['Derrière\tPRP\tderrière','la\tDET:ART\tle',  'télé\tNOM\tt']]

[[i.split('\t')[2] for i in subl] for subl in test_list]
```

**Output**

```
[['M', '.', 'Laudrel'], ['derrière', 'le', 't']]
```

Also, if you always need last index use `-1` as in index

```
[[i.split('\t')[-1] for i in subl] for subl in test_list]
```

Comment: thank you for taking the time to reply , i will try your answer and comeback to you.